# Sending 100 UDP packets per second with Python socket, how to reduce lags?

Tags: python, windows, sockets, udp, latency

I'm coding a realtime audio sharing tool via network, and I'm first trying with UDP packets (I will investigate with TCP later, but I first wanted to see the best I can get with UDP).

In the following code, `txmax` is the **biggest time it took to send a single UPD packet** (size ~ 1800 bytes) in the last 100 packets that have been sent. I observed:

- `txmax` is usually in the range 6 ms - 20 ms, which is ok.
- but once or twice a minute, `txmax` peaks at 250 ms, i.e. **at least one `sock.sendto(...)` takes 250 ms to send a single UDP packet of 1.8 KB!**

**Question: What could be the reason? How to reduce the UDP sending lags with Python `socket` library?**

Notes:

- My home Wifi network is probably not the bottleneck, I'm only sending ~ 100 packets x 1.8 KB = 180 KB / sec ~ 1.4 Mbit per second!
- I've already tried to set the process in `REALTIME_PRIORITY`

  ```
  import psutil, os
  psutil.Process(os.getpid()).nice(psutil.REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS)
  ```

  but it did not change anything.
- I've already tried to increase the socket's send buffer size:

  ```
  sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, 16384)
  ```

  but it had minor impact.
- If I run another process at the same time and the CPU peaks, this problem is more noticeable.
- `sock.setblocking(False)` seems to change the situation: the delay is now zero, or very close, but the code sometimes totally halts with:

  ```
  BlockingIOError: [WinError 10035] A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately
  ```

---

Reproducible example:

```
import time, socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
txmax = 0
i = 0
while True:
    # data = getdatachunk()  # this is always stable and takes ~ 10ms with no exception 
                             # for reproducibility, replaced with:
    time.sleep(0.010)
    data = b'A' * 1800

    s = time.time()
    sock.sendto(data, ("192.168.1.17", 5006))  # send UDP packet
    txmax = max(txmax, time.time() - s)

    if i % 100 == 0:
        print(txmax)
        txmax = 0

    i += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I'm surprised to see any delay, for most of your transmissions. On a Linux system, the default socket transmit buffer is much larger than 1800 bytes, e.g. `cat /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_default` on my system says `212992`. I tried running your code on my system, I mostly get something like `0.00015` i.e. 0.2ms (which still surprises me a bit. `ping` round-trip-time over ethernet is ~0.4ms. and i *thought* this UDP transmission should just be getting buffered, not waiting unless the buffer fills). After 300 seconds, I see nothing over 0.6ms.

Comment: Thanks for having run these tests @sourcejedi! Maybe on Windows, `socket` has a lower priority? (I'll update the question in a few seconds, with "blocking" vs "not blocking" tests)

Answer (score 1):

After extensive tests, two things improved massively the results:

- Set a timeout:

  ```
  sock.settimeout(0.050)
  ```

  With this, there is no more problems: `txmax`  falls to 1 ms all the time, and there is no more peak at 250ms.

  I even never experienced the exception mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout):

  > socket.settimeout(value)
  > Set a timeout on blocking socket operations. The value argument can be a nonnegative floating point number expressing seconds, or None. If a non-zero value is given, subsequent socket operations will raise a timeout exception if the timeout period value has elapsed before the operation has completed. If zero is given, the socket is put in non-blocking mode. If None is given, the socket is put in blocking mode.
- For the audio recording part (out of topic here), finally I noticed

  ```
  import psutil, os; psutil.Process(os.getpid()).nice(psutil.REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS)
  ```

  totally solved the problem of audio crackles